# Solution for text-to-speech (TTS) accessible by pure Python

Tags: python, speech-synthesis

I am running a Python 2.7 app on Google App Engine and would like to convert text to speech, preferably storing mp3/mp4/wav files in GAE itself. The Python libraries I have seen all have C dependencies and so cannot be deployed on Google App Engine.

Google Translate will do the job online but only for up to 100 characters, and I cannot find any pure Python libraries for merging sound files (my texts are typically much longer than that).

Is there a library or an online service that will allow my app to serve sound files created from texts. For now, I only need English TTS.

Comment: "`I am running a Python 2.7 app`" <=  there's [your problem](https://pythonclock.org/), right there.

Answer (score 1):

[MaryTTS](https://github.com/marytts/marytts) is a Java text to speech engine so you should be able to run it on GAE *or other such services.*

[This python example](https://github.com/marytts/marytts-txt2wav/tree/python) shows how to request it (running as a separate service on the same machine) to process some text and return via download a .wav file. You should be able to have it running in one instance and your python code accessing it from another.

Answer (score 1):

There are many options, here's how to save a spoken *hello world* using different libraries:

- Using [**gTTS**](https://pypi.org/project/gTTS/), Google's text-to-speech lib:

  ```
  import gtts
  tts = tts.gTTS('hello world', lang='en')
  tts.save('hello-world.mp3')
  tts.save('hello-world.wav')
  ```
- Using [**a Sapi wrapper**](https://github.com/DeepHorizons/tts):

  ```
  import tts.sapi
  voice = tts.sapi.Sapi()
  voice.say("Hello")
  voice.set_voice("Anna")
  voice.create_recording('output.wav', "This will be in a wav file")
  ```
- [**pyTTSx**](https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3) allows for TTS, but support for saving output as a file is [yet to be developped](https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/issues/7)